# phonegap sqlitelog error

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, webkit, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to execute my android application using phonegap but I'm having the following error when I execute a plugin that i created:

> 15:33:12.912: E/SQLiteLog(2249): (14) cannot open file at line
>   30174 of [00bb9c9ce4] 10-31 15:33:12.912: E/SQLiteLog(2249): (14)
>   os_unix.c:30174: (2) open(/CachedGeoposition.db) -  10-31
>   15:33:12.912: D/WebKit(2249): ERROR:  10-31 15:33:12.921:
>   D/WebKit(2249): SQLite database failed to load from
>   /CachedGeoposition.db 10-31 15:33:12.921: D/WebKit(2249): Cause -
>   unable to open database file 10-31 15:33:12.921: D/WebKit(2249):
>   external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) :
>   bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)

By the way, I'm not using a sqlite database

Comment: are you opening a new webview? If so you this a pretty benign error that you can ignore.